# Table Scan and Eager Spools on IN Predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running what I think is a fairly simple query, and I'm having getting absolutely atrocious return times on the query. When running the query, a sub query as a filter in an `IN` predicate is performing an Index scan and an Index Spool when used as part of the query, but runs an Index Seek when used outside of the `IN` predicate. I have no idea why, but the query is taking nearly 30 seconds to return zero records...

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.County
    , S.State
    , C.County_ID
FROM
    Leads L 
    INNER JOIN Inventory I ON L.Deleted = 0 AND L.Inv_ID = I.Inv_ID
    INNER JOIN County C ON C.County_ID = I.County_ID
    INNER JOIN State S ON C.State_ID = S.State_ID AND S.Active = 1
    INNER JOIN Contacts ON L.Contact_ID = Contacts.ID AND Contacts.Deleted = 0
WHERE
    L.Acct_ID = 204940
    OR L.Acct_ID IN (
        SELECT Accounts.Acct_ID FROM Accounts (NOLOCK) WHERE Accounts.Parent_Acct_ID = 204940
    )
ORDER BY
    S.State
    , C.County
```

Here's the relevant part of the execution plan of that query. It's running a scan on the Accounts table in the `WHERE` clause, with an estimated number of rows to be returned of over 260,000. The subselect actually returns 0 records.

[image]

When I run that simple select outside the above query, I get a straight index seek, against the exact same Index. The subselect returns 0 records. If I run the query without the `OR` statement I get ms response times, if I run the query with the `OR` statement, the query takes nearly 30 seconds to complete.

Here's the index that's being used for both the Scan and the Seek on the Accounts table (I know, it's a dta index, not my original database...)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Accounts_5_144719568__K32_50] ON [dbo].[Accounts] 
(
    [parent_Acct_ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [CompanyState]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How do I get the subselect to run an Index Seek instead of a Scan, and return in any sort of reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Unfortunately, way too many... However, the index that's used for the Seek when the sub is run separately, is the same one that's being used for the Scan. I've added the Index in question to the question.

Comment: How long does the subselect by itself run?  `SELECT Accounts.Acct_ID FROM Accounts (NOLOCK) WHERE Accounts.Parent_Acct_ID = 204940`

Comment: SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 4 ms.

Comment: Convert IN clause into EXISTS clause and see if you get better plan.My experience is IN clause often gives very inefficient query plan re-writing the query with EXISTS clause gives better query plan in those cases.

Comment: OR EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Accounts (NOLOCK) WHERE Accounts.Parent_Acct_ID = 204940
  AND L.Acct_ID = Accounts.Acct_ID
    )

Comment: That got rid of the Scan, and I have all Seeks now, but the query still takes more than 20 seconds to return 0 records. I think you've answered the question, but I personally still need to figure out where the issue is with this query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How big is your RS for the outer query? If you youse that IN-clause, for every row in it, he performs that subselect.

Comment: The leads table has over a million records in it, but the end result of the entire query is 0 (this particular custom doesn't have any yet). Perhaps I need to push the sub-select into an indexed temporary table in order to speed things up.

Comment: one further hint, try the CROSS APPLY operater to force a indexseek in your subselect.

Comment: Well the EXISTS gets me all Index Seeks (no scans at all) but doesn't actually improve the performance of the overall query.

Comment: Actually, a Indes Scan isn't always bad nor performance lowering. It depends ond different aspects, e. g. how is the density of your partitioning element in this case (I would think it is account-ID)? Low-Density: many Account-IDs with not so many corrosponding rows in the other tables --> Index Scan is preferable, but with High-Density: not that much Account-IDs with many corrosponding entrys in the other tables--> Index Seek.

Comment: Are your statistics on that table up to date? Also, how many different Parent_Acct_IDs are there in the table? A lack of distinct values can throw the engine off as it sometimes thinks it's easier to just scan through the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted all of you who gave me a hand, but this ended up being the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.County
    , S.State
    , C.County_ID
FROM
    Leads L 
    INNER JOIN Contacts ON L.Contact_ID = Contacts.ID AND Contacts.Deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN Inventory I ON L.Deleted = 0 AND L.Inv_ID = I.Inv_ID
    INNER JOIN Accounts ON L.Acct_ID = Accounts.Acct_ID
        AND ( Accounts.Acct_ID = 204940 OR Accounts.parent_Acct_ID = 204940 )
    INNER JOIN County C ON C.County_ID = I.County_ID
    INNER JOIN State S ON C.State_ID = S.State_ID AND S.Active = 1
ORDER BY
    S.State
    , C.County
```

Moving to a JOIN instead of a sub-select caused the query to run in 8ms instead of over 30 seconds. I know have straight index seeks in a nice cascade instead of a bunch of backwards filters and sorts to figure out who belongs in the query.

Comment: OK, thats what I pretty much was thinking of when I posted my answer :), my english is not the best, sorry...

Comment: The only difference is that yours included the sub-select, which still performed horribly. It seems that *any* of the solutions proposed that used the sub-select ran just as slow, or sometimes worse. Very strange.

Comment: This is subtly different from your original query. However, I assume there is  referential integrity between `Leads` and `Accounts` that mitigates the significance of the difference.

Comment: Correct. The sub select gets account IDs that are associated with the calling parent, so I can join on either of those columns and get the same result. I definitely did not expect switching to a JOIN with a filter to have such a drastic difference on the performance.

Comment: exactly. But I avoid pretty much every subselect I have to do, because of the fact that for every ROW in your outer RS you execute this whole SELECT. I try to avoid IN and EXITS too.

Comment: Given the extra information in your answer I extended my own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
        C.County
        , S.State
        , C.County_ID
    FROM
        Leads L 
        INNER JOIN Inventory I ON L.Deleted = 0 AND L.Inv_ID = I.Inv_ID (AND  L.Acct_ID = 204940
        OR L.Acct_ID IN (
            SELECT Accounts.Acct_ID FROM Accounts (NOLOCK) WHERE Accounts.Parent_Acct_ID = 204940
        ))
        INNER JOIN County C ON C.County_ID = I.County_ID
        INNER JOIN State S ON C.State_ID = S.State_ID AND S.Active = 1
        INNER JOIN Contacts ON L.Contact_ID = Contacts.ID AND Contacts.Deleted = 0
    ORDER BY
        S.State
        , C.County
```

Comment: please look at the logic of it with the OR and AND if it works correct. I'm just mentioning to you, to not filter the whole RS at the end with the WHERE-Clause, but to reduce the ROWS and the needed LOOPS and SCANS, by reducing the RS very early

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your query a little and changed the sub-query into a left join.

Give it a go, it should be easier for the engine to optimize or, if not, easier for you to optimize.

Before optimizing ensure your statistics are up to date.

```
SELECT
            [C].[County],
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County_ID]
    FROM
            [dbo].[Leads] [L] 
        JOIN
            [dbo].[Inventory] [I]
                ON [I].[Inv_ID] = [L].[Inv_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[County] [C]
                ON [C].[County_ID] = [I].[County_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[State] [S]
                ON [S].[State_ID] = [C].[State_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[Contacts] [Co]
                ON [Co].[ID] = [L].[Contact_ID]
        LEFT JOIN
            [dbo].[Accounts] [A] (NOLOCK)
                ON [A].[Acct_ID] = [L].[Acct_ID]
    WHERE
            [L].[Deleted] = 0
        AND
            [S].[Active] = 1
        AND
            [Co].[Deleted] = 0
        AND
            (
                [L].[Acct_ID] = 204940
            OR
                [A].[Parent_Acct_ID] = 204940
            )
    GROUP BY
            [C].[County],
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County_ID]
    ORDER BY
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County]
```

given the extra information in the OP's own answer, the query could be further simplified,

```
SELECT
            [C].[County],
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County_ID]
    FROM
            [dbo].[Leads] [L] 
        JOIN
            [dbo].[Inventory] [I]
                ON [I].[Inv_ID] = [L].[Inv_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[County] [C]
                ON [C].[County_ID] = [I].[County_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[State] [S]
                ON [S].[State_ID] = [C].[State_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[Contacts] [Co]
                ON [Co].[ID] = [L].[Contact_ID]
        JOIN
            [dbo].[Accounts] [A] (NOLOCK)
                ON [A].[Acct_ID] = [L].[Acct_ID]
                    OR [A].[Parent_Acct_ID] = [L].[Acct_ID] 
    WHERE
            [L].[Deleted] = 0
        AND
            [S].[Active] = 1
        AND
            [Co].[Deleted] = 0
        AND
            [L].[Acct_ID] = 204940
    GROUP BY
            [C].[County],
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County_ID]
    ORDER BY
            [S].[State],
            [C].[County]
```